# Can Camel have Two endpoints in different machines?

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to the concepts of Camel and I would like someone to confirm my findings so far.

**Please correct if wrong**

The way I see it, Camel has **Components**, which can have several communication interfaces called **Endpoints**. A Component can communicate with another component by sending a message to on of its Endpoints, which then will use a **Processor** to deliver it to the destination. I also read about **Routes** but I am not sure what they are used for because they seem to overlap in function with Processors (aka, they seem to be the same thing?)

- [Camel Routes and Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728260/camel-routes-and-endpoints)
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

**Please confirm if correct**

So far I believe that a Component (C1) in machine A can use an Endpoint (E1) to communicate with another component (C2) using its endpoint (E2) in machine B, by using websockets:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me in the first question or confirm my second one. Also, is there a better way to communicate between machines that doesn't involve using webscokets?

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Route` is what connects endpoints and processors together.  When you define a route in Camel it starts with a `Component` that exposes a communication `Endpoint`, invokes processors that implement the business logic of the route, and then can output the `Exchange` (the message being processed) to another `Endpoint` that is exposed by another `Component`.

Certain components allow Camel routes to communicate with endpoints in different machines.  For example, the JMS component can be used to communicate with other machines via JMS messages.  However, some components are limited to communicating with endpoints within the same VM like the SEDA component.

Camel provides many different ways to send data between machines (Here is a list of a few of them off the top of my head):

1. AMQP
2. JMS
3. Amazon SQS
4. HTTP
5. Mina
6. Netty

Take a look at the Camel Components page for a complete list: http://camel.apache.org/components.html